# Form validation library in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react js.Is there any form validation library in react js like angular has reactive forms and template driven forms and its own set of validation rules like valid,dirty,pristine.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/) it's very easy and complete. It has 14k stars on github, pretty good!